# Getting execption whenever it runs from process.start

Tags: c#, powershell, command-line

so im having this weird issue with a win 7 pc. I have this application that [runs this powershell script](https://gist.github.com/MichaelPote/92fa6e65eacf26219022) from a .bat file. 
This is the code:

```
public void GetLastestEarthBackground()
{
    var directoryPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Scripts");
    var vbsFile = Path.Combine(directoryPath, Settings.VBSFileName);

    if (File.Exists(vbsFile))
    {
        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                WorkingDirectory = directoryPath,
                Verb = "runas",
                UseShellExecute = true,
                FileName = "run.bat", //Settings.VBSFileName,
                Arguments = "//B //Nologo"
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

When i run it from my application i see this in the command line:

[image]

But if i double click on the batch file i get this resut:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a issue with user rights, the program running the script probably does not have the same rights as your user.

Comment: Ok, I have been trying to set the app to run as admin but i still get the same issue. I have added a `app.manifest` and i have tried to install it and use the option 'run as administrator'. Nothing helped so far.